# INTERVAL handling in BigQuery's GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY to obtain all end-of-month (EOM) dates between two dates. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array), indeed, GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY supports the MONTH keyword in the INTERVAL part:

```sql
SELECT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-12-31', '2022-03-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, the result is quite buggy:

[image: partial result of the query]

It seems that after February, the process get screwed and keeps 28 as the end of month until the final date.

Is there something I'm missing? Or maybe this is a bug?

Comment: You might consider using LAST_DAY() function.  **SELECT ARRAY(SELECT LAST_DAY(day) FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-12-01', '2022-03-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) day)**

Comment: Thank you @Jaytiger, this is exactly what I'm doing as a workaround. I was wondering if this behavior is expected or not

Comment: Not sure, but it seems to be expected. kindly check the documentation here. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_add

Comment: Well, that makes sense and should apply also to GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY as a caveat. Probably, the best approach to have a precise result is to generate all the start-of-month and then subtract a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jaytiger [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74097389/interval-handling-in-bigquerys-generate-date-array/74098182#comment130827776_74097389), this may be something expected, although not clearly documented. In the documentation of some date functions is reported (see for example [DATE_ADD docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_add)):

> Special handling is required for MONTH, QUARTER, and YEAR parts when
> the date is at (or near) the last day of the month. If the resulting
> month has fewer days than the original date's day, then the resulting
> date is the last date of that month.

As a workaround, if you want to obtain the EOM dates, this approach may be used:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(day, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-01-01', '2022-04-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) day
```

In other words, instead of generating the EOM dates, it is best to generate the start-of-month dates and the subtract a day.

Another approach is to use the method suggested by @Mikhail in his [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74100777/6258929).

Answer (score 1):

Consider also below approach (note use of LAST_DAY function)

```
select last_day(day, month) from
unnest(generate_date_array('2021-01-01', '2022-04-01', interval 1 month)) day
```